# implementing correct logic to find retention rate

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to implement retention rate as follows:

Retention rate = Number of retained users / number of churned users

Here is my code so far:

```
select round((
select count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as total_distinct_users
FROM table 
where    

   user_pseudo_id NOT IN (
   SELECT distinct user_pseudo_id
   FROM table
   WHERE event_name = "app_remove"
   
 )
 
 AND app_info.version in ('2.0.0',
'2.1.0',
'2.1.1',
'2.1.2',
'2.2.0'
)

 and device.operating_system='Android'


)



/

 (
select count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as total_distinct_users
FROM table 
where 

user_pseudo_id in (
 
   SELECT distinct user_pseudo_id
   FROM table
   WHERE event_name = "app_remove"
   
 )
 
 AND app_info.version in ('2.0.0',
'2.1.0',
'2.1.1',
'2.1.2',
'2.2.0')

 and device.operating_system='Android'




),2)
```

The logic seems correct to me, however the retention rate seems a bit too low (its less than one). So I wanted to ask; is this a correct way to implement my formula of retention rate? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I think your definition of retention is wrong. It should be retained users / total users, and generally it contains a install date and nth day dimensions.

Anyways, by accepting your definition, I simplified your query to summarise events by user first, and also count number of app_removed events.
In the second part, we only count the number of users and number of retained users.

```
with
users as 
(
   select 
      user_pseudo_id, 
      countif(event_name = 'app_remove') as app_remove
   from table 
   where
     app_info.version in (
         '2.0.0',
         '2.1.0',
         '2.1.1',
         '2.1.2',
         '2.2.0'
      )
      and device.operating_system='Android'
   group by 1
)
select countif(app_remove = 0) / count(*) as retention_rate
from users
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is correct.

Below are my interpretation on your SQL Query. You can see if it matches.

1st Query: Count of not fulfilling app remove, with all the other criterias fulfilled.

2nd Query: Count of fulfilling app_remove, will all the same other criterias fulfilled

You can consider to check if the criterias are too strict , 
or do segmentation (divide users into groups, with different criterias)